# Showing the map with mapquest

Tags: ios, mapquest

I didin't find any MapQuest SDK for iOS developing like the Android one, should i use the javascript with the Safari browser instead?

Comment: They also have this new thing now called "Google Maps". What a time to be alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the JavaScript API doesn't support being embedded into an iOS application, but a browser-based site should work, so you can give it a try! I don't have an exact date, but I do know that MapQuest is releasing an iOS SDK soon.

Another option, if you need an iOS application right now, is to use the MapQuest [Mobile Flash Maps API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash-mobile) with the latest version of Adobe Flash Builder, which can be used to create applications for iOS, Android, and BlackBerry.  There are more details in the [MapQuest Devblog](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2011/12/13/mobile-flash-maps-api-v7-0-7-released-with-dev-girl-coverage/).

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, i have downloaded the MQFlashMapsAPI, it's an `.swc`file, i don't know how to get started with that exciting API in my application, can you please forward me to some useful links showing how to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a demo application using MapQuest JavaScript API for iOS. I've changed the UserAgent string of UIWebView to Safari iOS browser. Now the JavaScript API detect my UIWebView as Safari iOS browser at has all the functionality like Zoom In/Out, Panning etc.

You can use the same thing to develop...iOS app...